# Cross thread manipulate WPF control error: cannot

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, invoke, dispatcher

I came across a problem while trying to manipulate the **FlowDocumentScrollViewer** control in WPF. I did searched through the internet about this kind of error, but found my problem is quite unique.

this is the code:

```
    delegate void delg_FlowDoc(FlowDocument fdoc);

    //Function provided for both internal calling and outside calling 
    public void setfDocDisplay(FlowDocument fdoc)
    {

        FlowDocumentScrollViewer display = this.fDocDisplay;  //control to be operated

        if (display.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            //called from own thread, just operate directly!

            string debug_check_ThreadName = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
            if (debug_check_ThreadName == "Thread_MainUI")
            {

                //Debug only, now current thread MUST be the thread
                //created the UI!!!!
                display.Document = fdoc;  //<-- Error this line
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //called from other threads, use Invoke()!
            delg_FlowDoc pFun = new delg_FlowDoc(setfDocDisplay);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(pFun, new object[] { fdoc });

            //display.Dispatcher.Invoke(pFun, new object[] { fdoc });
            //this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(pFun, new object[] { fdoc });
        }
    }
```

And an error occurred in line `display.Document = fdoc;`, saying still cannot access the control from a different thread.

And this is the detailed snapshot of error:
[image: Error!]

I am confused since:

1. I have already performed `display.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` to ensure current thread has the permission to operate on the control display.
2. I again add a `debug_check_ThreadName` to double ensure it's in the right thread for that moment.
3. I tried exactly the same code in another but smaller WPF project that is free of errors

But still got the same problem telling me I try to operate from a different thread.

I am not familiar with other properties of **Dispatcher** or **Invoke** etc. properties so I have no idea now to solve this problem.

If anyone can give me any hint of this error?

Thank you!

**[SOLVED]**

Thank you **500 - Internal Server Error**!

Since I am still shocked by the fact, I decide to put my understanding in the question to facilitate some one else have the same problem and saw this question.

I have now fixed the problem. It is because the **FlowDocument fdoc** is actually a type of UI control and created in another thread. So when the main windows thread want to operate that fdoc - although it has permission to **FlowDocumentScrollViewer display** - it doesn't have permission to the other control **fdoc** in this assignment sentence.

It's rather weird!! I thought fdoc is just a normal variable like a string or int vars... ><

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the control you (try to) assign to that's the problem - it's the source document that's not created on the UI thread.

Comment: And FlowDocument isn't freezable so you can't share it either

Comment: The source document is tied to the thread that it was created in - it's like a UI control in that regard.

Comment: So it's like the _FlowDocument_ object is a kind of UI control rather than a normal variable like _string_? it's so hard to understand this point...

Comment: Yes, I believe the reason is that it has properties that are dependent on the output device it was created for.